# Regarding JSON parsing error

Tags: php, json, api, parsing, weather-api

```
<?php
$url     = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=YOURAPI";
$json    = file_get_contents($url);
$data    = json_decode($json, true);
$data['city']['name'];

foreach ($data['list'] as $day => $value) {
  echo $todaystemperature = $value[temp][max];
}
?>
```

This has been working suddenly stopped working some reason. I keep getting on  `file_get_contents`. Not sure what make this code mess

Comment: Well running CURL from command line brings back `{"cod":401, "message": "Invalid API key. Please see http://openweathermap.org/faq#error401 for more info."` where as a browser brings back a response so perhaps they change their connections requirements, or your key hit some limit when not being used from a browser. (Also if that is a key specific to you you should modify/remove it)

Comment: @Eurasia. I have provided with the result. Have a check and let me know about your expectations.

Comment: Thank you for these steps.. much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON Data needs to be parsed based on the JSON response that you are getting.

#### Steps for Getting the Json Data using PHP

- First you have to get the data has the json_response.
- Then you have to make the json response to decode through the json code using `json_decode($json,TRUE)`
- After that you can use `foreach()` for splitting up of the array that you get based on the decoded value.

While running the above URL that you have given in the code i am getting the output as follows.

**Obtained JSON:**

```
{"coord":{"lon":-0.13,"lat":51.51},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":284.66,"pressure":1016.88,"humidity":68,"temp_min":284.66,"temp_max":284.66,"sea_level":1024.55,"grnd_level":1016.88},"wind":{"speed":4.91,"deg":97.501},"clouds":{"all":92},"dt":1476377768,"sys":{"message":0.1769,"country":"GB","sunrise":1476339772,"sunset":1476378552},"id":2643743,"name":"London","cod":200}
```

Hence after following up the process you can get the values like this.

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
 $url     = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?  q=London,uk&appid=a1fc2c19d548237a56e0edd7b79b3ebc";
 $json    = file_get_contents($url);
 $data    = json_decode($json, true);
 echo $temp = $data['main']['temp']; // To convert the data to Celsius by hitting the API called api.openweathermap. 
?>
```

> **Note:**  `$data['main']['temp']`  - Make sure that you get data over here and then you will succeed over here.

Output for the Json Parse is as follows for the above obtained JSON:

**String Parse:**

```
{

    "coord":{
        "lon":-0.13,"lat":51.51},"weather":[
        {
            "id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04d"}],"base":"stations","main":{
        "temp":284.66,"pressure":1016.88,"humidity":68,"temp_min":284.66,"temp_max":284.66,"sea_level":1024.55,"grnd_level":1016.88},"wind":{
        "speed":4.91,"deg":97.501},"clouds":{
        "all":92},"dt":1476377768,"sys":{
        "message":0.1769,"country":"GB","sunrise":1476339772,"sunset":1476378552},"id":2643743,"name":"London","cod":200

}
```

**Js Eval:**

```
{

    "coord":{
        "lon":-0.13,"lat":51.51},"weather":[
        {
            "id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04d"}],"base":"stations","main":{
        "temp":284.66,"pressure":1016.88,"humidity":68,"temp_min":284.66,"temp_max":284.66,"sea_level":1024.55,"grnd_level":1016.88},"wind":{
        "speed":4.91,"deg":97.501},"clouds":{
        "all":92},"dt":1476377768,"sys":{
        "message":0.1769,"country":"GB","sunrise":1476339772,"sunset":1476378552},"id":2643743,"name":"London","cod":200

}
```

Hence when you do the `json_decode()` for the above obtained JSON string you have the out put as follows.

```
array (
  'coord' => 
  array (
    'lon' => -0.13000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125,
    'lat' => 51.50999999999999801048033987171947956085205078125,
  ),
  'weather' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'id' => 804,
      'main' => 'Clouds',
      'description' => 'overcast clouds',
      'icon' => '04d',
    ),
  ),
  'base' => 'stations',
  'main' => 
  array (
    'temp' => 284.66000000000002501110429875552654266357421875,
    'pressure' => 1016.8799999999999954525264911353588104248046875,
    'humidity' => 68,
    'temp_min' => 284.66000000000002501110429875552654266357421875,
    'temp_max' => 284.66000000000002501110429875552654266357421875,
    'sea_level' => 1024.549999999999954525264911353588104248046875,
    'grnd_level' => 1016.8799999999999954525264911353588104248046875,
  ),
  'wind' => 
  array (
    'speed' => 4.910000000000000142108547152020037174224853515625,
    'deg' => 97.501000000000004774847184307873249053955078125,
  ),
  'clouds' => 
  array (
    'all' => 92,
  ),
  'dt' => 1476377768,
  'sys' => 
  array (
    'message' => 0.176900000000000001687538997430237941443920135498046875,
    'country' => 'GB',
    'sunrise' => 1476339772,
    'sunset' => 1476378552,
  ),
  'id' => 2643743,
  'name' => 'London',
  'cod' => 200,
)
```

Hence after getting the array it seems to be of `Single Object` with array for some of the keys that has been obtained.

[image]

Hence you can fetch the data only from this output obtained using the loop operators called `foreach()`. Hence by using the `foreach()` the array data will be coming in the loop as single manner and then it will manipulate the result.

Answer (score 0):

your code seems not right, the url you are using is giving following response

```
    {
  "coord": {
    "lon": -0.13,
    "lat": 51.51
  },
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 804,
      "main": "Clouds",
      "description": "overcast clouds",
      "icon": "04d"
    }
  ],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 284.66,
    "pressure": 1016.88,
    "humidity": 68,
    "temp_min": 284.66,
    "temp_max": 284.66,
    "sea_level": 1024.55,
    "grnd_level": 1016.88
  },
  "wind": {
    "speed": 4.91,
    "deg": 97.501
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 92
  },
  "dt": 1476377646,
  "sys": {
    "message": 0.0048,
    "country": "GB",
    "sunrise": 1476339772,
    "sunset": 1476378553
  },
  "id": 2643743,
  "name": "London",
  "cod": 200
}
```

In the above json response i can not find any key with 'list' that is why your code breaks. This code should be fine to get the temp of the city

```
<?php
 $url     = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=a1fc2c19d548237a56e0edd7b79b3ebc";
 $json    = file_get_contents($url);
 $data    = json_decode($json, true);
 echo $temp = $data['main']['temp'];
?>
```

Comment: I don't know... It may problem with my browser.. I get  Warning: file_get_contents(http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather? q=London,uk&appid=a1fc2c19d548237a56e0edd7b79b3ebc): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in /home/pray4mal/public_html/pray-dev/weather/weather.php on line 27

Comment: On line  $json    = file_get_contents($url);

Comment: can you access it in your browser try hitting it in your browser

Comment: '<?php
 $url     = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=a1fc2c19d548237a56e0edd7b79b3ebc";
 $json    = file_get_contents($url);
 $data    = json_decode($json, true);
 echo $temp = $data['main']['temp'];
?>'

Comment: it is working but it seems the data is wrong 284.66.. I am asking help from api.openweathermap

Comment: to convert it to Celsius  $data['main']['temp'] – 273.15

Answer (score -1):

```
    $json = file_get_contents('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=a1fc2c19d548237a56e0edd7b79b3ebc');

    $data = json_decode($json,true);
    OR
   $data = json_decode($json);
    echo "<pre>";

    print_r($data);

    exit;
```

Comment: What's this? Answers should have an explanation.

Comment: you are getting an issue .Thats why i have provide code for you .Try it

Comment: You need to explain what was wrong and how your code fixes it. This is supposed to be an educational site, not just a repository of code snippets.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the result

```
<?php
 $url     = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&units=imperial&cnt=1&lang=en&appid=YOURAPI";
 $json    = file_get_contents($url);
 $data    = json_decode($json, true);
 echo $temp = $data['main']['temp'];
?>
```